I can't call the function on C
I'm new to C programming. For educational purposes, I decided to create a modular project - a linear, single-linked list and a function that would delete elements by key. The problem is that I can't call this function in the main file. Help please (ノ_<。)
//list.h
#ifndef ___LIST_H
#define ___LIST_H

//structure
typedef struct List_Item *List;
struct List_Item
{
    int key;
    List next;
};
//funstion prototipe
void DeletingByKeyCStyle(List**, int);

#endif ___LIST_H

//list.c
#include "List.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

List InsertBegin(List p, int x)
{
    List q=(List)malloc(sizeof(List_Item));
    q->key=x;
    q->next=p;
    return q;
}

void DeletingByKeyCStyle(List *p, int x) {
    List q;
    while (*p != NULL && (*p)->key == x) {
        q = *p;
        *p = (*p)->next;
        free(q);
    }
    if (*p == NULL) return;

    q = *p;
    while (q->next != NULL) {
        if (q->next->key == x) {
            List temp = q->next;
            q->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
        } else {
            q = q->next;
        }
    }
}

//main.c
#include "List.h"
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    List p=NULL;
    for (int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        p=InsertBegin(p,i);

    DeletingByKeyCStyle(&p, 4); //doesn't work

The following error is generated during compilation:
" error: no matching function for call to 'DeletingByKeyCStyle'
DeletingByKeyCStyle(&p, 4);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'List *' (aka 'List_Item **') to 'List **' (aka 'List_Item ***') for 1st argument
void DeletingByKeyCStyle(List**, int);
^
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
"

Define "doesn't work"

Please specify exactly what "Doesn't work" means. Do you get an error at compile time, at run time, or some other unexpected effect? Also please describe exactly what you expect

Clion writes: "No matching function for call to 'DeletingByKeyCStyle'" and compilation is not happening

Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. And if you get a build error, copy-paste the full and complete error into the question as well. Also tell us how you build the program, and what flags and options you use when building. Please [edit] your question to improve it.

The function prototype does not match .. in the header you have List ** and the implementation has List *

Welcome to SO. Do you include the header? What is p in main? Pleae provide a complete minimum example.

Did you #include "list.h"?

And please note that it's generally not a good idea to create type-aliases of pointers (like List). That could lead to mistakes like your mismatching function declarations.

I have edited my question. The p in the main file is a pointer to the structure. I'm not sure about this, but List is already a pointer to List_Item, then it turns out that List* p is equal to List_Item** p. Is this really the case or am I wrong?

The message shows that you are using C++ compiler.

You have different function signatures.
list.h:
void DeletingByKeyCStyle(List**, int)

list.c:
void DeletingByKeyCStyle(List *p, int x)

Based on your implementation, you probably need to use that one in the list.h:
void DeletingByKeyCStyle(List*, int)


I love you, man <3
